# How do I initialize an array of a non-built-in type in a c++ constructor initializer list?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initializer-list

In C++, I am trying to initialize an array of a non-built-in type in a constructor initializer list.  Starting from the code:

```
class bar {
  int i1,i2;
public:
  bar(i1,i2);
}
class foo {
  bar bar1,bar2;
public:
  foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) : bar1(a,b),bar2(c,d) {};
}
```

I would like to replace bar1 and bar2 with an array:

```
bar allbars[2];
```

How to I change the initializer list to initialize allbars?

Comment: why dont you show what you tried and the errors you get?

Comment: `bar(i1,i2);` - that doesn't even compile.

Comment: foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) : allbars{ bar(a,b), bar(c,d) } {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a proper constructor for `bar` first.

```
class bar {
  int i1,i2;
public:
  bar(int one, int two)
  : i1(one)
  , i2(two)
  {};
};

class foo {
  bar allbars[2];
public:
  foo(int a, int b, int c, int d)
  : allbars{ bar(a,b), bar(c,d) }
  {};
};
```